# unable to compile typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, leiningen

I wanted to use [lein-typescript](https://github.com/vbauer/lein-typescript) plugin to compile typescript files.
I put my `typescript` files into `src` folder

[image]

I added needed dependencies to `project.clj` and ran `lein deps`

```
(defproject tree-model-system "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  :plugins [[lein-cprop "1.0.1"]
            [lein-cljsbuild "1.1.5"]
            [lein-immutant "2.1.0"]
            [lein-typescript "0.1.3"]
            [lein-npm "0.6.2"]]

  :typescript {:sources ["src/ts"]
               :out-dir "target"
               :module :amd
               :declaration true
               :source-map true
               :remove-comments true
               :preserve-const-enums true
               :supress-implicit-any-index-errors true
               :target :es6
               :debug true}

  :npm {:dependencies[[systemjs "0.19.40"]
                      [core-js "^2.4.1"]
                      [rxjs "5.0.1"]
                      [zone.js "^0.8.4"]
                      [angular-in-memory-web-api "~0.3.0"]
                      ["@angular/common" "~4.0.0"]
                      ["@angular/compiler" "~4.0.0"]
                      ["@angular/core" "~4.0.0"]
                      ["@angular/forms" "~4.0.0"]
                      ["@angular/http" "~4.0.0"]
                      ["@angular/platform-browser" "~4.0.0"]
                      ["@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" "~4.0.0"]
                      ["@angular/router" "~4.0.0"]]
        :devDependencies[[concurrently "^3.2.0"]
                         [lite-server "^2.2.2"]
                         [typescript "~2.1.0"]
                         [canonical-path "0.0.2"]
                         [tslint "^3.15.1"]
                         [lodash "^4.16.4"]
                         [karma "^1.3.0"]
                         [karma-chrome-launcher "^2.0.0"]
                         [karma-cli "^1.0.1"]
                         [karma-jasmine "^1.0.2"]
                         [karma-jasmine-html-reporter "^0.2.2"]
                         [protractor "~4.0.14"]
                         [rimraf "^2.5.4"]
                         ["@types/node" "^6.0.46"]
                         ["@types/jasmine" "2.5.36"]]}
```

It created `node_modules` folder and installed required dependencies there including `typescript`

[image]

But when I try to run `lein ts` I get

`"node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

What is the problem?

Comment: The command `lein ts` is using a wrong command `node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc` is needs to be `node_modules\typescript\.bin\tsc` with `.bin` in the path. The `tsc` compiler is inside the `.bin` folder. Try to run this on your command line: `node_modules\typescript\.bin\tsc` to see what happening

Comment: @Diullei with `.bin` it is unable to find the path specified

Comment: @Diullei what is odd is that in `bin` folder `tsc` itself is a file without any extension

Comment: Try to expand the `.bin` folder, inside your `node_modules` (see your screenshot). Its supposed to have a `tsc` file inside, can you check?

Comment: @Diullei oh I get it. Indeed in `node_modules\.bin` there is `tsc` bat file.

Comment: @Diullei when I run `node_modules\.bin\tsc` it shows `version` with options so it seems to work if I run it from there. How to configure `project.clj` to use that `tsc` file instead of `typescript\bin` one?

Comment: If it is showing the TypeScript version because It's missing a `tsconfig.json` file on your root dir. I never used this `lein ts` command before, so I cant help to setup this. Sorry...

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: @Diullei yes, I am using Windows

Comment: If you open the `node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc` you will see an instruction at the first line: `#!/usr/bin/env node`. In a quickly look on `lein-typescript` code I saw that the code is trying to open a process to run this file. It will work on linux because linux knows about `#!/usr/bin/env node`. Windows does not knows about this instruction.

Comment: So basically windows ignores that line and trying to run it raw like `cmd>ts`. I see.

Comment: Yes, windows is skipping this line. Since the file has no extension windows does not know how to execute it.

Comment: @Diullei well that sucks, I guess I'll need a workaround